# Call child class method from instance of parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance

I have about 8 view controllers in my app, and i have a function in each one that does the exact same thing. I was hoping to be able to condense it into one central function that can perform the task for all 8. The function would need to receive an instance of itself so that it could perform the task on the appropriate view controller, but since i have no idea which one is being passed i set the instance type as UIViewController *. That way, i'd be able to receive any of the view controllers. The problem is i have to execute a method from this method, and since each method is custom to those child classes to UIViewController and im PASSING UIViewController, i can't access the functions from the instance. Is there some way to do this? Access a child class method from an instance of the parent class? Here's some code:

```
- (void)changeIsFullscreen:(UIViewController *)viewController { // <-- Right here is the 
                           // ^^^ instance of the class that's passed to the function. I 
                           // can't pass the child because there are so many different 
                           // children that will be using it.
    if (isFullscreen == NO) {
        [viewController setIsFullscreen:YES]; // Right here is the child
                                             // class method that i need to call.
                                            // They all have the method, and if they 
                                           // don't i could use try/catch blocks to 
                                          // catch the error if there was some way to do it.
    } else {
        [viewController setIsFullscreen:NO]; // Right here is the child
                                             // class method that i need to call

    }
}
```

I know one way to do this would be to extend UIViewController, create the method in THAT class, and extend all the other child view controllers from the new class i just extended. I don't know if that is the correct way to accomplish this task, though. Is it? Or should I do it another way?

Comment: what is the name of the method you need to call?

Comment: it's a custom method. it's in the code i posted; setIsFullscreen. it accesses an instance-specific variable and returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something obvious here, but if all of your view controller subclasses implement this method, it sounds like they should all derive from some intermediate class. So, you'd have a class that derives from UIViewController and implements -changeIsFiullscreen, and all of your view controllers are derived from *that* class.

Comment: right, well i dont actually DO that yet. I'll have to go through and change it so that they all do. But, it's a good idea and it needs to be done so that's what ill do. i just wanted to make sure that was the correct way of doing it. Thank you for the answer.